# How to quantify bin migrations in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I have two different calculations of the same number and I want to study the bin migrations that will follow from migrating from calculation A to B. **Is there a Pandas one-liner that will give me a matrix with migration probabilities between bins for two columns in a dataframe?**

Example:

Here's a dataframe:

```py
df=pd.DataFrame({
'A':[1.1,1.3,1,2.2,2.1,2.3,3,3.1,3.2],
'B':[1.2,1.1,2.2,2.1,2,2.1,1.1,3.4,3.2]})
```

I can do a naive binning:

```py
df['A']=np.floor(df['A']).astype(int)
df['B']=np.floor(df['B']).astype(int)
```

So, given this dataframe:

```
   A  B
0  1  1
1  1  1
2  1  2
3  2  2
4  2  2
5  2  2
6  3  1
7  3  3
8  3  3
```

I want to build this matrix:

```
    1   2   3
---------------
1| 2/3 1/3  0
2|  0   1   0
3| 1/3  0  2/3
```

One can see that it show the migration probabilities (OK, "frequencies") between bins.

- 1 has a probability of 2/3 to remain 1 and 1/3 to become 2.
- 2 has a probability of 1 to remain 2.
- 3 has a probability of 1/3 to become 1 and 2/3 to remain 3.

I could probably calculate the migration probabilities by hand, but experience tells me that there is *always* a pandas oneliner that does the job cleaner and quicker.

The Dataframe.corr() method will treat the two columns as variables to build a corellation matrix between. That's not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for correlation between values.

Comment: Try looking at Pysals's implementation of Markov transition matrices too: https://pysal.readthedocs.io/en/v1.8/library/spatial_dynamics/markov.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
df_confusion = pd.crosstab(df['A'], df['B'])/df['A'].nunique()
```

O/P:

```
B         1         2         3
A                              
1  0.666667  0.333333  0.000000
2  0.000000  1.000000  0.000000
3  0.333333  0.000000  0.666667
```

Comment: Was that even one line or rather a "one-half-liner"?